# Point that is inside multiPolygon of geojson isn't found with geojson-geometries-lookup

Tags: javascript, geojson

Here is the link to the [replit](https://replit.com/@GeorgyKotlyar/GeoSuck#index.js)
The coordinate is very much inside the multiPolygon of CA_LAX. I've checked serveral times but it just doesn't work. Any tips on how to fix my code would be greatly appreciated!
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
const geojson = JSON.parse(data)
const glookup = new GeoJsonGeometriesLookup(geojson);

const point1 = {type: "Point", coordinates: [34.05220031738281, -118.24369812011719]};
console.log(glookup.getContainers(point1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the coordinates to `[longitude, latitude]`, i.e. `[-118.24369812011719, 34.05220031738281]`, you'll get the desired result.